# Store Node children in mutable R-tree - Scala

Tags: scala, nodes, children, r-tree

What is the best collection to use for storing the children of a Node in a mutable R-tree.

Since my tree is mutable my guess would be something like ListBuffer, List, ArrayBuffer. But I am not sure which one to pick. I need a collection that has decent complexities both in removal and insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented with a combination of `ArrayBuffer, PriorityQueue`

A simple non-exhaustive example

```
object RTree {

  /**
   * Construct an empty RTree.
   */
  def empty[A]: RTree[A] = new RTree(Node.empty[A], 0)

  /**
   * Construct an RTree from a sequence of entries.
   */
  def apply[A](entries: Entry[A]*): RTree[A] =
    entries.foldLeft(RTree.empty[A])(_ insert _)
}


case class RTree[A](root: Node[A], size: Int) {

  /**
   * To be considered equal, two trees must have the same
   * number of entries, and each entry found in one should be found in
   * the other.
   */
  def ===(that: RTree[A]): Boolean =
    size == that.size && entries.forall(that.contains)

  /**
   * Trees can only be equal to other trees. Unlike some other
   * containers.
   *
   * This means comparing an RTree[Int] and an RTree[Long] will
   * always return false.
   */
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case rt: RTree[_] =>
        Try(this === rt.asInstanceOf[RTree[A]]).getOrElse(false)
      case _ =>
        false
    }


  /**
   * Insert a value into the tree at (x, y), returning a new tree.
   */
  def insert(x: Float, y: Float, value: A): RTree[A] =
    insert(Entry(Point(x, y), value))

  /**
   * Insert an entry into the tree, returning a new tree.
   */
  def insert(entry: Entry[A]): RTree[A] = {
    val r = root.insert(entry) match {
      case Left(rs) => Branch(rs, rs.foldLeft(Box.empty)(_ expand _.box))
      case Right(r) => r
    }
    RTree(r, size + 1)
  }

  /**
   * Remove an entry from the tree, returning a new tree.
   *
   * If the entry was not present, the tree is simply returned.
   */
  def remove(entry: Entry[A]): RTree[A] =
    root.remove(entry) match {
      case None =>
        this
      case Some((es, None)) =>
        e.foldLeft(RTree.empty[A])(_ insert _)
      case Some((e, Some(node))) =>
        e.foldLeft(RTree(node, size - e.size - 1))(_ insert _)
    }

  /**
   * Return a sequence of all entries found in the given search space.
   */
  def search(space: Box): Seq[Entry[A]] =
    root.search(space, _ => true)

  /**
   * Return a sequence of all entries found in the given search space.
   */
  def search(space: Box, f: Entry[A] => Boolean): Seq[Entry[A]] =
    root.search(space, f)
```

Comment: why should I prefer ArrayBuffer to ListBuffer for the children?

Comment: List buffer is implemented on Linked Lists and Array buffers is based on Arrays so typically index lookups are faster in Arrays compared to linked lists. You can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712877/difference-between-array-and-list-in-scala. If this was helpful please do accept the answer.