# Array.empty == Array() gives false yet both appear equal type- and value-wise?

Tags: scala

While reviewing a code change I found `Array.empty` not `Array()` that I would consider more idiomatic. I was then surprised to have learnt that `==` them gives `false` yet they appear equal type- and value-wise.

```
scala> Array.empty == Array()
res1: Boolean = false

scala> Array.empty
res2: Array[Nothing] = Array()

scala> Array()
res3: Array[Nothing] = Array()
```

Could anyone explain why is so?

Comment: How does `==` work in Scala? Reference identity like in Java? Or more like `equals`?

Comment: @Thilo, it depends on the type

Comment: I believe it is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738850/384442

Comment: The debate between `Array.empty` and `Array()` might not be a dupe. If they don't close it as argumentative and opinioned, I'd vote for `empty` as more explicit and one less opcode (because no empty vararg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually more of a Java question. Because in Java, which Scala's `Array` is exactly using, array equality is *identity equality*.

```
// scala                   compiles as such Java           is equal to
Array.empty == Array() === Array.empty.equals(Array()) === false
```

The proper way to check Array equality based on structure is:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(Array.empty, Array()) === true
```

Arrays are a very special beast on the JVM - intuition often fails with them. 
Scala had to carry over this definition in order to keep compatibility with Java stuffs.

Comment: Or `Arrays.deepEquals`. Sad situation.

Comment: Interesting. How could I know in Scala REPL that Array is based on Java's?

Comment: not "in the REPL" but everywhere. Well - books or scaladocs - there's a lot of links in there http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Array

Comment: Actually the test compiles to `BoxesRunTime.equals`. Special equality could have been implemented there. You can witness that Scala arrays are Java arrays by entering `Array(1)` and then `:javap -` to see `newarray` in the constructor of the result.

Comment: In Scala, you can use `sameElements` for comparing `Seq`s, and there are implicit conversion that make this work for `Array` as well: `Array(1) sameElements Array(1)`. Unfortunately `Array.empty sameElements Array()` doesn't work because of issues with type parameters.