# The right way to represent an array of bytes (SHA256) in a case class

Tags: scala

I need to store a sequence of bytes (a hash) in a case class.

My first approach has been to use an `Array[Byte]` but it breaks the equality property of the case class. The next example fails.

```
"compare arrays" in {
   case class CaseClassWithHash(id: Int, hash: Array[Byte])
   CaseClassWithHash(0, Array[Byte](192.toByte, 168.toByte)) == CaseClassWithHash(0, Array[Byte](192.toByte, 168.toByte)) shouldBe true
}
```

So my question is, which is the best way to represent the array of bytes:

- I'm not going to manipulate it.
- I need == working in the case class (previous unit test).
- Memory usage is critical.
- It is going to be always 32 bytes (sha256).

P.S. [Case Class equality for Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341016/case-class-equality-for-arrays) is not an answer to my question. I'm asking for the right replacement of an Array to represent a SHA256 value and of course, overwrite the equals function is not the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case Class equality for Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341016/case-class-equality-for-arrays)

Comment: @YevheniiPopadiuk The question is different. I'm looking for the right Class to represent the array of bytes.

Comment: Sorry. I see now.

Comment: @YevheniiPopadiuk No problem at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Array` to `Seq` seems to work for me. I'm not sure about memory usage but Seq is pretty reliable and quick.

```
case class CaseClassWithHash(id: Int, hash: Seq[Byte])

println(CaseClassWithHash(0, Seq[Byte](192.toByte, 168.toByte)) == CaseClassWithHash(0, Seq[Byte](192.toByte, 168.toByte)))
// true
```

As the [linked potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154676/the-right-way-to-represent-an-array-of-bytes-a-hash-in-a-case-class/53155101#comment93200387_53154676) suggests (link points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341016/case-class-equality-for-arrays)), if you insist on using Arrays then you will need to define a custom `equals` method.

Comment: That question is different. I don't want to use an Array but I don't know which is the right replacement.

Comment: Pretty sure that Seq is not the best bet for this case. The default implementation is an immutable List. I think that it is a liked list so probably I will use more than the double of memory. Maybe Vector is a better solution.

Comment: And of course, I don't want to overwrite the equals function. I want to replace the type.

Comment: If memory is crucial, then Vector is the solution. It start "branching" after 32 elements and it memory consumption is low. See [benchmark](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html).

Comment: @YevheniiPopadiuk Vectors are brilliant and I did have them in my original draft of this answer as an alternative. Not sure why I took that part out.

Comment: I heard somewhere that Seq automatically converts itself to either a Vector or List under-the-hood depending on which is more efficient for the task at hand. I could be misremembering though