# Spark testing base strange validation failure

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

When I execute `sbt test` in order to test a spark application utilizing `spark-testing-base`

```
Map("result" -> Array(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 0)) did not equal Map("result" -> Array(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 0))
```

for a test case of

```
val input: Map[String, Any] = Map("digits" -> Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0))
val expectedOutput: Map[String, Any] = Map("result" -> Array(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 0))
val result = SimpleContext.runTheJOb(session, input)
```

Minimal example can be found https://github.com/geoHeil/apache-spark-restAPI-example

## edit

the whole test case  directly

```
class SimpleTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext with DatasetSuiteBase {

  test("SimpleContext should multiply input numbers by 3") {
    val session = spark

    val input: Map[String, Any] = Map("digits" -> Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0))
    val expectedOutput: Map[String, Any] = Map("result" -> Array(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 0))
    val result = SimpleContext.runTheJOb(session, input)
    assert(expectedOutput === result)
  }
}
```

Comment: @LostInOverflow the minimal "code" is already included. But if you prefer to have the whole code I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks! Your gists can become invalid at any point and this questions should serve not only you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Scala `Array`s, being Java arrays under the hood, are not comparable using `==` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737711/why-doesnt-arrays-function-return-true-for-array1-2-array1-2) for an explanation).

Example:

```
scala> Array(1,2) == Array(1,2)
res0: Boolean = false
```

However most of the other collections *are* comparable:

```
scala> List(1,2) == List(1,2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Your options would be to either use one of the other collections (like a `List`) or to use `deep` for comparisons:

```
scala> Array(1,2).deep == Array(1,2).deep
res22: Boolean = true

scala> Array(1,2).deep == Array(1,3).deep
res23: Boolean = false
```

Comment: so Array(1, 2) should equal (Array(1, 2)) via http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers should be the solution.