# How do I compare two arrays in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, pattern-matching

```
val a: Array[Int] = Array(1,2,4,5)
val b: Array[Int] = Array(1,2,4,5)
a==b // false
```

Is there a pattern-matching way to see if two arrays (or sequences) are equivalent?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481149/why-does-array0-1-2-array0-1-2-not-return-the-expected-result and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737711/why-doesnt-the-array-equality-function-work-as-expected answer from those is to use `sameElements`

Comment: This _is_ a duplicate, but `sameElements` doesn't do the trick for nested arrays, because it's not recursive.  Moritz' answer below is the appropriate one now (which should probably be added to the older answers).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to change your last line to

```
a.deep == b.deep
```

to do a deep comparison of the arrays.

Comment: This is the canonical way to do it.  But just a warning to the performance-hungry: this _does_ create an entire new collection on both sides, so it's not the most efficient possible way to do it.

Comment: @Rex yes, it does create a new collection, but this does not mean, that it is inefficient. Look at the implementation of the method `deep`. It creates a collection, that forwards all calls of the `apply` method to the original array.

Comment: @E. Verda - Hm, the implementation is not what I'd expected.  But it does a pattern match for _every element_ of the array, which is expensive if it's an array of primitives, and for nested arrays it _re-wraps the array_ on every access.  If the arrays are almost entirely different it's inexpensive; for matching close arrays, it's going to be expensive compared to a recursive non-constructive solution.

Comment: @LucaMolteni:do you mean `Array.equals`? That doesn't seem to provide a deep comparison.

Comment: There is also `java.util.Objects.deepEquals`

Comment: @matanster `deepEquals` is deprecated in the latest versions.

Comment: @stas Good to know. I wonder what else has changed in this regard. Any good Scala libraries for working with deeply nested structures?

Comment: if you want to compare arrays, regardless of the order of elements though, you should sort them first.
`arr1.sorted == arr2.sorted`
hope this will help.

Comment: `deep` has been removed in Scala 2.13 / 3 and onwards

Answer (score 117):

From [Programming Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155956):

```
Array(1,2,4,5).sameElements(Array(1,2,4,5))
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, even though the other one is the accepted.

Comment: This was the one that helped my FreeSpec test to pass. :-)

Comment: looks like this method only supports Array of Integer. I tried Array of string( df1.columns.sameElements(df2.columns))) it didnt work

Answer (score 22):

```
  a.corresponds(b){_ == _}
```

> Scaladoc: `true` if both sequences have
>   the same length and `p(x, y)` is `true`
>   for all corresponding elements `x` of
>   `this` wrapped array and `y` of `that`,
>   otherwise `false`

Comment: Array is not a sequence http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array, so this will require some (probably implicit) redirections.

Answer (score 14):

For best performance you should use:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(a, b)
```

This is very fast and does not require extra object allocation. `Array[T]` in scala is the same as `Object[]` in java. Same story for primitive values like `Int` which is java `int`.

Comment: I ran `val t0 = System.nanoTime(); val r = (java.util.Arrays.equals(a,b)) ; val t1 = System.nanoTime(); t1 - t0` on this sample code and very similar code for the other examples ... This option was way faster than the other examples.

Answer (score 5):

As of Scala 2.13, the `deep` equality approach doesn't work and errors out:

```scala
val a: Array[Int] = Array(1,2,4,5)
val b: Array[Int] = Array(1,2,4,5)
a.deep == b.deep // error: value deep is not a member of Array[Int]
```

`sameElements` still works in Scala 2.13:

```
a sameElements b // true
```

Comment: This should be just a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't look like most of the provided examples work with multidimensional arrays. For example

```
 val expected = Array(Array(3,-1,0,1),Array(2,2,1,-1),Array(1,-1,2,-1),Array(0,-1,3,4))
 val other = Array(Array(3,-1,0,1),Array(2,2,1,-1),Array(1,-1,2,-1),Array(0,-1,3,4))

    assert(other.sameElements(expected))
```

returns false, throws an assertion failure

```
deep doesn't seem to be a function defined on Array.
```

For convenience I imported scalatest matchers and it worked.

```
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers._
other should equal(expected)
```