# How to check if an array of arrays contains a specific array in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In scala, how can I check if a multidimensional array of Int contains an array, for instance:

```scala
val test = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1))

test.contains(Array(1, 2)) // this results to false

test.contains(test(0)) // this results to true
```

So it seems scala is comparing the object reference too, in the first case, despite having the same elements, it is a different object, hence returning false. Is this right?

In the second case, I'm testing against one of the same objects already contained in the list, hence returning true.

How can I achieve the expected result, i.e., checking if a multidimensional array in Scala contains a specific array?

I have seen this is possible with tuples, but not with arrays.

Comment: I think It helps for you to understand why it can't. https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/unsafe/array_comparison.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you require raw performance, identified by proper [measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600699/5205022) with say jmh, or require Java interop, then try to avoid `Array` and instead use Scala collections proper such as `List`:

```
List(List(1,2), List(2,1)).contains(List(1,2))  // res2: Boolean = true
```

If you must use `Array`, then try combination of `exists` and [`sameElements`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862672/5205022) like so

```
test.exists(_.sameElements(Array(1,2)))         // res1: Boolean = true
```

[Why doesn't Array's == function return true for Array(1,2) == Array(1,2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737711/why-doesnt-arrays-function-return-true-for-array1-2-array1-2)

Comment: Or stop using useless arrays and use **List** or **ArraySeq** instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sameElements`:

```
test.exists(_.sameElements(Array(1, 2)))
```