# How to improve this scala code which is checking if two byte arrays are same?

Tags: java, scala, compare

I have a method to compare two byte arrays. The code is java-style, and there are many "if-else"s.

```
def assertArray(b1: Array[Byte], b2: Array[Byte]) {
  if (b1 == null && b2 == null) return;
  else if (b1 != null && b2 != null) {
    if (b1.length != b2.length) throw new AssertionError("b1.length != b2.length")
    else {
      for (i <- b1.indices) {
        if (b1(i) != b2(i)) throw new AssertionError("b1(%d) != b2(%d)".format(i, i))
      }
    }
  } else {
    throw new AssertionError("b1 is null while b2 is not, vice versa")
  }
}
```

I have tried as following, but it's not simplified the code much:

```
(Option(b1), Option(b2)) match {
    case (Some(b1), Some(b2)) => if ( b1.length == b2.length ) {
       for (i <- b1.indices) {
        if (b1(i) != b2(i)) throw new AssertionError("b1(%d) != b2(%d)".format(i, i))
       }
    } else {
       throw new AssertionError("b1.length != b2.length")
    }
    case (None, None) => _
    case _ => throw new AssertionError("b1 is null while b2 is not, vice versa")
}
```

Comment: You may want to post this question on codereview.stackexchange.com. It's a perfect fit for "how to improve my code" questions.

Comment: As this is Scala code, why have you tagged it [java]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you're doing this as an academic exercise, how about

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(b1, b2)
```

The description:

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of bytes are equal to one
>   another. Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the
>   same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they
>   contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array
>   references are considered equal if both are null.

I will admit to this being 'java style' :-)

Since you're throwing AssertionErrors, you can remove all of the else's:

```
def assertArray(b1: Array[Byte], b2: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
  if (b1 == b2) return;

  if (b1 == null || b2 == null) throw new AssertionError("b1 is null while b2 is not, vice versa")  

  if (b1.length != b2.length) throw new AssertionError("b1.length != b2.length")

  for (i <- b1.indices) {
    if (b1(i) != b2(i)) throw new AssertionError("b1(%d) != b2(%d)".format(i, i))
  }
}
```

If, as I suspect, you're actually using this within JUnit tests (hence the assertArray), then you can use a trick which I often do, compare the string representations of the arrays:

```
def assertArray2(b1: Array[Byte], b2: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
  assertEquals(toString(b1), toString(b2))
}

def toString(b: Array[Byte]) = if (b == null) "null" else java.util.Arrays.asList(b:_*).toString
```

which will give you the same outcome (an AssertionError), with where the differences are.

Comment: +1: The first test can be simplified to `if (b1 == b2) return;`

Comment: @Peter I don't think that would work, since `==` on Arrays is reference equality: see this Q&A. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2481149/770361 However from Rex's answer there it sounds like you could explicitly wrap the arrays to make it work.

Comment: `==` works for arrays in that if b1 and b2 are both null, it will be true, and if b1 and b2 are the same object, it will be true.

Comment: @Peter Just to be clear Arrays.equals returns true if the elements are the same as well, but the objects are different.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell, True, which is why only `if (b1 == null || b2 == null)` can be replaced with `if (b1 == b2)`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the first test (java.util.Arrays.equals(b1, b2)), rather than the first test in the method. You're right of course :-)

Answer (score 6):

The standard library provides `sameElements` for exactly this purpose:

```
scala> val a1 = Array[Byte](1, 3, 5, 7); val a2 = Array[Byte](1, 3, 5, 7); val a3 = Array[Byte](1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
a1: Array[Byte] = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)
a2: Array[Byte] = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)
a3: Array[Byte] = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

scala> a1 sameElements a2
res0: Boolean = true

scala> a1 sameElements a3
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: No, it fails if one, a1 or a2 is null.

Answer (score 1):

One possible simplification:

```
def assertArray(b1: Array[Byte], b2: Array[Byte]) {
    (Option(b1), Option(b2)) match {
        case (None, _) => 
            throw new AssertionError("b1 is null")
        case (_, None) => 
            throw new AssertionError("b2 is null")
        case (Some(Size(b1Size)), Some(Size(b2Size))) if b1Size != b2Size  => 
            throw new AssertionError("b1.length != b2.length")
        case (Some(b1), Some(b2)) if b1 zip b2 find (c => c._1 != c._2) isDefined => 
            throw new AssertionError("Arrays do not match")
        case _ => // everything is OK
    }
}

object Size {
    def unapply[T](arr: Array[T]): Option[Int] = Some(arr.size)
}
```

Probably can be improved even more, but at least it does not have nested `if`s and external loops.

Answer (score 1):

A minor improvement to Matthew's solution could be, to return all diffs and not just the first:

```
def assertArray (b1: Array[Byte], b2: Array[Byte]): Unit = {

  def diffs [T] (a: Array[T], b: Array[T]) = 
    (a.zip (b).filter (e => (e._1 != e._2)))

  if (b1 == null && b2 == null) 
    return;
  if (b1 == null || b2 == null) 
    throw new AssertionError ("b1 is null while b2 is not, vice versa")  
  if (b1.length != b2.length) 
    throw new AssertionError ("b1.length != b2.length")
  val delta = diffs (b1, b2)
  delta.map (d => throw new AssertionError ("" + delta.mkString ))
}
```

Test invocation:

```
val ab = (List ((List (47, 99, 13, 23, 42).map (_.toByte)).toArray,
  (List (47, 99, 33, 13, 42).map (_.toByte)).toArray)).toArray

assertArray (ab(0), ab(1))
// java.lang.AssertionError: (13,33)(23,13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using tail recursive:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def assertArray[T](b1: Array[T], b2: Array[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : Unit = (b1, b2)  match{
    case (null, null) => 
    case (null, a) if a != null => throw new AssertionError 
    case (a, null) if a != null => throw new AssertionError  
    case (Array(), Array()) => 
    case _  => if (b1.length != b2.length ||  b1.head != b2.head ) throw new AssertionError  else assertArray(b1.tail,b2.tail)  
}
```

and the test casees

```
assertArray(null,null)
assertArray(Array[Byte](),null)
assertArray(null,Array[Byte]())
assertArray(Array[Byte](),Array[Byte]())
assertArray(Array[Byte](),Array[Byte](1))
assertArray(Array[Byte](1,2,3),Array[Byte](1,2,3))
assertArray(Array[Byte](1,3),Array[Byte](1))
```

How about this [https://gist.github.com/1322299 link](https://gist.github.com/1322299)